# QTP - Bitmap CheckPoint

Tags: bitmap, qtp, hp-uft

I'm trying to use bitmap checkpoint and able to record it in UFT properly. But when I try to use the same TestScrit in another machine which has QTP11.0, it's not working.

So immediately when I've checked in OR, I've noted that the image I captured is not at all there and got some error like `Information cannot be retrieved for the selected test object`

```
msgbox Browser("xyz").Page("abc").WebTable("table").Check(CheckPoint("Bmp_Test"))
```

This line has returned **TRUE** when I've executed in UFT (where I actually recorded the checkpoint), but returned **FALSE** in QTP11.0. Please check and help. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can open tests opened with UFT once ever again with QTP.

Comment: Even I had this doubt, so just exported the local OR as shared repository and tried to access in QTP installed machine. But that too didn't help - still the reason why I'm standing in this query is that we used to share the ORs and use among QTP & UFT (** never faced any object recognition issue). But in `Bitmap` case only it's not working out.... any clue plzz?!?